# Return partial view from ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

On button click I called a js function which call as action method. But if json result is 0 (not error), I want to redirect to partial view.
**JS function:**

```
function AssignButtonClicked(step, parent, show) {
    alert("coming: " + step + " parent: " + parent + " show is : " + show);

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        url: "/Jobs/PassInstructionTest",

        data: "{stepGuid: '" + step + "', parentGuid: '" + parent + "'}",

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        dataType: "json",

        success: function (response) {

            alert("resp is : " + response);
            if (response == '0') {
                alert('qa called!');
                $("#forqa").show();                   
            }
            if (response == '1') {

            }
        },

        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText + " error for fail");
        },

    });
    return false;
}
```

**Action method in controller:**

```
public ActionResult PassInstructionTest(Guid stepGuid, Guid parentGuid, string show)
{
  bool isQA = false;
  if (!isQA)
  {
    return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
    return PartialView("MyPartialView");
  }
}
```

When `MyPartialView` is called, it is throwing error as Error executing child request.

Please provide me the solution.

Comment: When your `isQA` getting true?

Comment: To test I'm passing it as false. If QA is true then I want to open a Modal popup, else execute the return partial view. partial view is getting called but its not redirecting it it and throwing error as Error executing child request. Do I need to change javascript function ?

Comment: And this click event also exists in a partial view..

Answer (score 0):

Convert Html to string then pass this as json.

```
public virtual string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        //Original source code: http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        this.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, viewName);


            var viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }



  public ActionResult PassInstructionTest(Guid stepGuid, Guid parentGuid,string show)
  {
   bool isQA = false;
   if (!isQA)
   {
      return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   else
   {
       return update_section = new
            {
          ShippingMethodUpdateHtml =   this.RenderPartialViewToString("MyPartialView", null)
            },
   }
  }
```

Comment: update_section is giving error.. And I was tried                                                                                     
                  return Json(new
                    {
                    statusCode = 10,
                       statusMessage = "The person has been added!",
                       personHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("LoadJob", treeView)
                    });

Even though throwing error as Error executing child request, and response is coming as alert display.